# context deadline exceeded error when running Gitlab Runner on Windows/Docker

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I get this error when I run my CI using a Gitab-Runner installed on Windows or within Docker, precisely just after I do docker build:

```
1 [internal] load .dockerignore
#1 ERROR: no active session for deyvlborrpy89ibo2fvk9xxb9: context deadline exceeded
#2 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#2 ERROR: no active session for deyvlborrpy89ibo2fvk9xxb9: context deadline exceeded
------
 > [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile:
------
------
 > [internal] load .dockerignore:
------
no active session for deyvlborrpy89ibo2fvk9xxb9: context deadline exceeded
```

I have read this might be related to certificates but in my CI file I have:

```
DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
```

Which should disable TLS.

Anyone knows how to fix this? Or basically how to setup Gitlab runner to work with docker: 19-dind.

Thank you in advance and regards.

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: I do not recall very well I can say I am using now version docker:19.03.1-dind not sure if that was the solution

Comment: I seem to be past this now too and I think my root cause had to do with low memory of the system. Maybe the timeout had to do with slow response times due to heavy paging/swapping happening?

Comment: I do not think that applies to my case as I did not change system or any memory/cpu load as far as I am aware. Reading my original message I mentioned that it might be related to certificates and I remember wasting a ton of time due to those. I also remember that disabling TLS did not work as expected or something like that. Did you do something in particular to fix it? Did you try the version I mentioned?